# How to reuse code from parent class efficiently? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, software-design

Is there any nice way to reuse code from parent class other than just copy paste all code from parent class and replace some code if I want to change few lines of code are in the middle of the code?

1. I can't change code in parent class directly.
2. Most of codes are same but only few lines of code are different.
3. Real code is hundreds lines of code and only few lines of code is different between parent and child class.

parent class:

```
class Parent():
    def example(self):
        doSomething1()
        doSomething2()
            ...
        doSomething100()
        doSomething101()
            ...
        doSomething200()
        return
```

child class:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def example(self):
        doSomething1()
        doSomething2()
            ...
        doSomething100()
        doSomethingNew() #add a new line
        #doSomething101() #delete a line
        doSomethingReplace() #replace a line
            ...
        doSomething200()
        return
```

Comment: If the method in the parent class is hundreds of lines long, then you're just stuck with a badly designed parent class. There's not much you can do about that, unfortunately.

Comment: Why is it not possible to break the hundred line `example` method in the parent class into separate methods such that one of the methods in the middle can be wholly replaced in the child class?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see, you can't change the parent class.

Comment: Override the `doSomething101` method as well in the `Child` class: `def doSomething101(self): self.doSomethingNew() self.doSomethingReplace()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke the parent version of an overloaded method from the child using the `super()` syntax then perform additional operations on the returned value.  That is not exactly the same thing as what you are asking, but I believe that is the best you can do as a practical matter.

Example:

```
class Parent:
    def perform_task(self, x):
        x += 10
        return x

class Child(Parent):
    def perform_task(self, x):
        x = super().perform_task(x)
        x *= 2
        return x

c = Child()
print(c.perform_task(5))
```

Output:

```
30
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the following in order not to re-write code found in the parent class, while you slightly change the child class:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, eye_color, length):
        self.eye_color = str(eye_color)
        self.length = length

    def display(self):
        print('Eye color: {0} ---- Length: {1}'.format(self.eye_color, self.length))


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, gender, parent):
        super().__init__(parent.eye_color, parent.length)
        self.gender = str(gender) #child slightly changed with the addition of new attribute

    def display(self):
        super().display()
        print('Gender: {0}'.format(self.gender))

x = Parent("Blue", 2)
y = Child("Men", x)

print(x.length, x.eye_color)
print(y.gender, y.length)

x.display()
print()
y.display()
```

**Output**

```
2 Blue
Men 2
Eye color: Blue ---- Length: 2

Eye color: Blue ---- Length: 2
Gender: Men
```

When a method in a subclass has the same name, same parameters or signature and same return type(or sub-type) as a method in its super-class (like the method `display()`), then the method in the subclass is said to override the method in the super-class. The version of a method that is executed will be determined by the object that is used to invoke it.

Also, if you wanted your child class to be a **COPY** of your parent class then you would simply do the following:

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, eye_color, length):
        self.eye_color = str(eye_color)
        self.length = length

    def display(self):
        print('Eye color: {0} ---- Length: {1}'.format(self.eye_color, self.length))

class Child(Parent):
    pass

y = Parent ('stack',3)
x = Child('Overflow',2)

print(x.length, x.eye_color)
x.display()
y.display()
```

Use the `pass` keyword when you do not want to add any other properties or methods to the class.

You can also both change and append the attributes of the superclass in your subclass by doing something like this:

```
class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, gender, parent):
        super().__init__(parent.eye_color, parent.length)
        self.gender = str(gender)
        parent.length += 2

x = Parent("Blue", 2)
y = Child("Men", x)

print(x.length, x.eye_color)
print(y.eye_color, y.length)

x.display()
y.display()
```

This would add 2 to the length, transforming the display output to:

```
2 Blue
Blue 3
Eye color: Blue ---- Length: 2
Eye color: Blue ---- Length: 3
```

If you want to completely change an attribute in the child class and not increment/decrement it like I did above, simply substitute `+=` sign with `=`

Did you have any other questions on how to append and reuse code in a sub-class?